# Get image cover from first page pdf file on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, image-processing, windows-phone-8.1

How to get image cover from first page pdf file on windows phone 8.1.

In windowsrt (windows 8.1) i use this code:

```
private PdfDocument _pdfDocument;
private async Task RenderCoverBuku(string pdfFileName, uint PDF_PAGE_INDEX)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder koleksibuku = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("koleksibuku", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                StorageFile pdfFile = await koleksibuku.GetFileAsync(pdfFileName);
                //Load Pdf File

                _pdfDocument = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(pdfFile); ;

                if (_pdfDocument != null && _pdfDocument.PageCount > 0)
                {
                    //Get Pdf page
                    var pdfPage = _pdfDocument.GetPage(PDF_PAGE_INDEX);

                    if (pdfPage != null)
                    {
                        // next, generate a bitmap of the page
                        StorageFolder thumbfolder = await installedLocation.CreateFolderAsync("thumb", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                        StorageFile jpgFile = await thumbfolder.CreateFileAsync(pdfFileName + ".png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        if (jpgFile != null)
                        {
                            IRandomAccessStream randomStream = await jpgFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
 await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(randomStream);
 await randomStream.FlushAsync();

                            randomStream.Dispose();
                            pdfPage.Dispose();
                            //await this.resfreshcontent();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                //rootPage.NotifyUser("Error: " + err.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

            }
        }
```

But in windows phone:

```
private PdfDocument _pdfDocument (using Windows.Data.Pdf)
```

cannot be recognized. Is there any alternative code to this?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows.Data.PDF is not support on Windows Phone 8.1. The best option would be to use a 3rd party library to parse the file for you.

You might want to look at if there is a 3rd party library you can use or possibly do the extraction on a server instead